# What exactly does "lebendig" mean?

Tags: word-usage

Does it mean "alive", "lively" or both?

And am I using it properly in my translation of the title song from the [Sound of Music](http://www.allmusicals.com/lyrics/soundofmusicthe/soundofmusic.htm)?

> Lebendig sind die Berge,
> Mit dem Klang der Musik.
> Mit alten Liedern,
> tausender Jahre.

> Die Berge erfüllen mich,
> Mit dem Klang der Musik.
> Dann singt mein Herz gerne
> Jedes Lied.

Comment: It can mean both, but "lebendig mit" is not a good translation of "alive with". "Von" or "durch" instead of "mit" is better.

Comment: I was quite surprised when I first heard that both "e" 's in that word are  open. I had expected a closed "e" followed by a schwa, as in "leben". Explanation someone? (I feel that this is not important enough to warrant a new question).

Comment: @Georges: I'd pronounce it exactly as you describe.

Comment: @Georges: It might be important enough for a second question. Clearly, it is a special case. Which is kind of why I asked the first one.

Comment: I like 'mit' more than 'durch'. And if, then 'vom Klang der Musik' - not 'von'. But 'from the sound of music' or 'by the sound of music' would have been possible in Englisch as well, so why did the author choose 'With'? I would keep it.

Comment: @Georges: Please do ask about "lebendig" as a new question! I wouldn't pronounce it correctly if I hadn't looked it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed your translation of *"alive"* is correct here:

> lebendig = *alive* (or *"lively"*, depending on context)
>
> lebhaft = *lively*

However, I can't resist to suggest improvements for the following lines:

> Lebendig werden die Berge
> mit dem Klang der Musik.
> Mit alten Liedern
> aus tausenden Jahren.
>
> Die Berge sind erfüllt
> mit dem Klang der Musik.
> Mein Herz singt mit jedem
> Lied, das es hört.

Comment: correct answer; I just want to add, that *[lebendig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lebendig)* has a second meaning, which is *lebhaft*: *"Alexander ist ein sehr lebendiges Kind.*"

Comment: I was just about to edit this in when I was blocked by your edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

To me it has always meant "living, existing proof". An audio example would be from this clip from an EasyGerman video, as this was the first that came to my mind when I saw this. With the context of being said, I think it helps in understanding.

[Video Here](https://youtu.be/91M6rPc4Hqc?t=255)